# What does a "scrolling range" means?

Tags: c, winapi

I am currently learning about scrollbars, and I encountered the term "scrolling range", but I am not sure what it means exactly, I think it means one of the following two definitions:

Say I have a scrollbar with a min position of 0, and a max position of 99.

1) The scrolling range is 100.

2) The scrolling range is 0 to 99.

Which one of these two definitions is correct?

Comment: More information than you ever wanted about scroll bars at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787527.aspx#scroll_position_and_range)

Comment: Scrolling range means 0 through the (number of lines - 1) for vertical scrolling, since indexing starts from 0

Answer (score 2):

You have `100` possible values in range from (including) `0` to `99`.